# Optimizing java (controller and service) code to work faster

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating online store, using spring mvc. So the point is when you create new product you need to upload picture for new product. I am using Cloudinary service, so when you upload image server grabs it, sends it to the Cloudinary gets response, gets image url from response and writes that url to the base. And all that goodness is working like 5 seconds, is there anyway to optimize this code so it will work faster, by the way this project is a test project for getting job, so i want it work good) here is the code that i wrote
Controller, it gets product with filled info and image like a MultipartFile :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createProduct(MultipartFile image, Model model, @ModelAttribute(name = "product") @Valid ProductDto product, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException {
   productValidator.validate(product,bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
        return "admin/create";
    } else {
        productService.saveProductDto(product,image);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createProduct(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("product", new ProductDto());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
    return "admin/create";
}
```

After that it goes to product service :

```
    @Override
public Product saveProductDto(ProductDto productDto, MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
    List<Image> list = transformImageToList(image);
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setCategory(categoryService.findById(productDto.getCategoryId()));
    product.setDescription(productDto.getDescription());
    product.setTitle(productDto.getTitle());
    product.setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
    product.setImages(list);
productDao.create(product);
    return product;
}

@Override
public Product saveProduct(Product product, Long categoryId, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Product deprecatedProduct = productDao.findById(product.getId());
    if (file.getSize() != 0) {
        List<Image> list = transformImageToList(file);
        product.setImages(list);
    } else {
        product.setImages(deprecatedProduct.getImages());
    }
    product.setComments(deprecatedProduct.getComments());
    product.setCategory(categoryService.findById(categoryId));
    productDao.update(product);
    return product;
}

@Override
public List<Image> transformImageToList(MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
    Image dbImage = new Image();
    List<Image> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (image.getSize() == 0) {
        dbImage.setUrl("http://placehold.it/300x300");
        list.add(dbImage);
        return list;
    } else {
         dbImage.setUrl(imageService.uploadFile(image));
         list.add(dbImage);
        return list;
    }
```

This ProductService uses imageService
imageService :

```
    Map<String, String> configuration() {
    Map<String, String> clouMap = new HashMap<>();
    clouMap.put("cloud_name", "dehsjhkzx");
    clouMap.put("api_key", "925657455192194");
    clouMap.put("api_secret", "hLAMwN8M-PtICNCtfr32hNIOFIE");
    return clouMap;
}

public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convertedImage = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    file.transferTo(convertedImage);
    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(configuration());
    Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(convertedImage, new HashMap());
    convertedImage.delete();
    return (String) uploadResult.get("secure_url");
}
```

and after that the code finishes So i get MultipartFile in controller and then i cast it to File and then send to server, by the way i will make the ImageService to resize image to 300x300 so in future it will be even more slower. Is there any way to refactor this code so that it will work faster

Image entity :

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String url;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

Product Entity :

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String title;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description;

private Double price;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "product_image", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "image_id") })
private List<Image> images;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "product_comment)
```

Comment: Maybe more suitable in code review? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just provide an image load indicator and limit the size allowed

Comment: First set a temporary image, process the uploaded image in the background and update the database when it's done. Most likely, this will require some sort of notification of the client so that it can refresh the image or at least an automatic refresh after a few seconds.

Comment: To upload image in the background I need to use multithreading ?

Comment: I would put my money on making this process asynchronous (assuming that there are some other data along with file to be saved), as soon as you get file, write it to disk and push a message to queue to be processed by a consumer which will upload image to Cloudinary and then updates the DB, I agree there will a latency in process but still it's better than waiting 5 sec.